# Angular - Foundation Equalizer Not Working

Tags: css, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I can't get Foundation Equalizer (the JS to get divs to be the same height) to work.

The demo itself isn't working. I'm using Foundation v6.1.2

So I'm using it in a ng-view and in the index file I have:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main as main">

<ng-view></ng-view>

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>

<script> $(document).foundation(); </script>

</body>
```

And in the HTML I'm just trying to get the demo working, namely using the code:

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="medium" id="test-eq">
  <div class="medium-4 columns">
    <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
      <img src= "assets/img/generic/square-1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-4 columns">
    <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et, ante.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-4 columns">
    <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
      <img src= "assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work??

Thanks

Comment: I do not see your full code here, but in my knowledge, the foundation script or any jquery script that you are using is not supposed to work with the angular. Because at the time when those scripts are ready, the DOM is not generated by Angular yet. You have to do some tricks to make your foundation script to be loaded later than the DOM is. Another way, you can find the equalizer Angular directive that is implement the same functionality and use it instead. (Until this time, pineconellc Foundation does not support this feature yet)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new instance of Equalizer to make it work like so

```
var elem = new Foundation.Equalizer(element, options);
```

Usage example

```
angular.module('app').component('user', {
  controller: UserController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  template: `
    <div class="row js-equalizer" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="medium" id="test-eq">
      <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
          <img src= "assets/img/generic/square-1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et, ante.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
          <img src= "assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
});

function UserController() {
  const vm = this;
  vm.$onInit = function() {
    new Foundation.Equalizer($('.js-equalizer'));
  }
}
```

Notice that I add `.js-equalizer` to same element as `data-equalizer` attribute.

You can learn more by reading documentation here: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html